# "Add a new Geonode plugin extension" doesnt work

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, extensions, node-js, geonode

I have a question. In this part of the geonode tutorial (https://training.geonode.geosolutionsgroup.com/master/GN4/mapstore_client/005_EXTENSION.html), I get the following error while running "npx @mapstore/project create extension". The versions of npm and node are correct. I am using an Ubuntu 22.04 VM on Windows 11. Does someone have an idea?

```
**(my_geonode) geonode@geonode-Virtual-Machine:/opt/geonode-project/my_geonode/src/my_geonode$ npx @mapstore/project create extension**
../csrc/addon.cc: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE convert(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../csrc/addon.cc:10:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToObject()’
   10 |   Local<Object> inputBuffer = info[0]->ToObject();
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /home/geonode/.cache/node-gyp/14.7.0/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:62,
                 from ../csrc/addon.cc:1:
/home/geonode/.cache/node-gyp/14.7.0/include/node/v8.h:2822:44: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2822 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~
/home/geonode/.cache/node-gyp/14.7.0/include/node/v8.h:2822:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make: *** [addon.target.mk:137: Release/obj.target/addon/csrc/addon.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/geonode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 6.2.0-1016-azure
gyp ERR! command "/home/geonode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/node" "/home/geonode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/geonode/.npm/_npx/6054/lib/node_modules/@mapstore/project/node_modules/ttf2woff2
gyp ERR! node -v v14.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```